# How to interpolate a series in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a problem in the interpolation of a series. I want to interpolate a series for example,`[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]`, and I want to get the series like `[1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5]`, is there an easy way to get this in `numpy`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [np.arange(start, end, step)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(1, 5, 0.5)
array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
```

To incorporate it with your series:

```
series = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
step = 0.5

np.arange(series[0], ( series[-1] + step ), step)
#=> array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
```

Comment: I think you mean `np.arange` (one 'r').